# c read string is causing a crash

Tags: c, string, strcmp, getchar

```
 int iPassCode, iNumber = 0;

void main()
{
    iNumber = get_name();
    iPassCode = get_code();
    name_strucutre();
}

int get_name()
{
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    cName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = getchar();
    if(strcmp(cName,"leia"||"Leia"))
    {
        iNumber = 1;
    }
    if(strcmp(cName,"darth"||"Darth"))
    {
        iNumber = 2;
    }
    if(strcmp(cName,"r2d2"||"R2D2"))
    {
        iNumber = 3;
    }
    if(strcmp(cName,"solo"||"Solo"))
    {
        iNumber = 4;
    }
    if(strcmp(cName,"jabba"||"Jabba"))
    {
        iNumber = 5;
    }
    if(strcmp(cName,"yoda"||"Yoda"))
    {
        iNumber = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        iNumber = 0;
    }
    return(iNumber);
}

int get_code()
{
    printf("Please enter your pass code: ");
    scanf("%d", iPassCode);
    return (iPassCode);
}
```

I got a couple of my functions here. One of them I think its the `get name()` function is causing the program to crash. Right now all I'm trying to do is gather the name and the pass code from the user and pass the info back to `main()`. I don't want to pass the whole name back though just a singular number.

Comment: `MAX_NAME_LEN` ???

Comment: `"leia"||"Leia"` is not doing what you think it's doing. You need two separate `strcmp` calls, or a `stricmp` variant. (And you've misspelt the lower case version of a certain Sith lord).

Comment: `#define MAX_NAME_LEN 42`     Forgot to mention I had this at the beginning

Comment: First, learn to use a debugger!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues, let us analyze them one by one

1. First of all,

   ```
   cName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = getchar();
   ```

   is invalid because

   - As per the latest standard, *default to `int`* is no longer a standard. You need to have the data type defined
   - A single call to `getchar()` reads one `char`. You need a loop, at least.

   You need to change to something like

   ```
   char cName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = {0};
   ```

   and then, loop over `getchar()` to read the input.

   Otherwise, for better, use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read and store the input.
2. That said, you cannot compare multiple strings in a single call like

   ```
   if(strcmp(cName,"leia"||"Leia"))
   ```

   this is essentially

   ```
   if(strcmp(cName,1))
   ```

   which is again illegal. You can make use [`strcasecmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp) to ignore the case. Otherwise, to be strictly standard-conforming, you have to use separate `strcmp()` calls to compare the string with each validator.

   *and yes, `strcmp()` returns `0` on success (match)*.
3. You are writing

   ```
   scanf("%d", iPassCode);
   ```

   which should be

   ```
   scanf("%d", &iPassCode);  //missed the address-of
   ```

After all these, from a coding style point of view, let me add that, `return` is a keyword, don't make it look like a function call.

Comment: so do this? `cName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = fgets();`

Comment: @JMBTaylor no, that's not the syntax at all. Please read the linked man page.

Comment: ahh got it. The link is for a linux fgets and a little hard to understand for a beginner but all i needed to change it to was `gets(cName);`

Comment: @JMBTaylor `gets()`? __no, never__. I have given you the link to `fgets()`, right?

Comment: yes but `fgets()` as I understand it reads from a file. I don't want to read the name from a file in this function.

Comment: @JMBTaylor `stdin` will be the _filename_ in case you want to read from standard input.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `strcmp(cName,"leia"||"Leia")` is equivalent to `strcmp(cName, 1)`.

The sub-expression `"leia"||"Leia"` is *true* which in C is equivalent to `1`.

If you want to check if a string is equal to one or another, you need two `strcmp` calls: `strcmp(cName,"leia") == 0 || strcmp(cName,"Leia") == 0`.

Comment: Or something like `stricmp`, although I can never remember if that's standard C or not.

Comment: @Bathsheba Nope, that's a Windows CRT specific function. The C standard have no case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how about `strcasecmp()`? [POSIX]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these errors :

- You are using

  scanf("%d", iPassCode);

in order to read, but you have declared

```
int iPassCode;
```

whereas `scanf` needs to read a pointer.

Replace it with

```
scanf("%d", &iPassCode);
```

- Another error is the way you compare strings. Replace all your comparisons with the following format :

  ```
  if ( (strcmp(cName,"something") == 0) || (strcmp(cName,"something") == 0) )
  ```
- Also, you cannot have `cName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = getchar();` as a valid declaration.
- Finally I suppose that you have defined `MAX_NAME_LEN` somewhere, otherwise you should.

Comment: That was an over looked error but I don't think the program got that far because it still crashes before notifying me of that.

Comment: @JMBTaylor I updated my post with more errors that I see, take a look :)